# Isomorphic groups: $(\mathbb Q[\sqrt 2],+)$ is isomorphic to $(\mathbb Q^2,+)$

Tags: abstract-algebra

If $K = \{ a + b \sqrt{2} : a, b \in \mathbf{Q} \}$. Show that $(K, +)$ is isomorphic to $(\mathbf{Q}, +) \times (\mathbf{Q}, +)$

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Please note the $\LaTeX$ edits I did to your post.

Answer (score 2):

Hints:

Define

$$\phi: K\to \Bbb Q\times\Bbb Q\;,\;\;\phi(a+b\sqrt2):=(a,b)$$

Prove now that $\,\phi\,$ is a well defined homomorphism of (abelian) groups and find its kernel and image...